# How can I implement italic HTML format of text in Android in Yahoo email client, or native mail client

Tags: android, email, android-intent

I have to implement a text in italic, so I have used HTML formatting.
In gmail app it works fine but in native mail client, yahoo mail app, or outlook, I cant see italicised text.

below is the sample code:

```
Html html = null;
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("text/plain");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"konypsteam@gmail.com"});
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "testMail");
//i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , html.fromHtml(body));
i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, html.fromHtml(body));
try { 
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Any help?

Comment: try Html.fromHtml("<i>Hello</i>");

Comment: I have tried the same. In my sample code, you will find : i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, html.fromHtml(body)); where body = "<i>some text</i>"

Comment: I have the same issue here with Mailbox and Yahoo mail. Has anyone ever get this working in those mail clients?